# How to embed a dll into Memory

Tags: windows-mobile, embed

Can anybody tell me how to embed a dll into Windows mobile Memory.

Comment: You will have to do a bit more research. Your question is broad and vague.

Answer (score 0):

You want to embed something into Read Only Memory via software?

Comment: Yes..i need to embed my dll into memory via software

Comment: My point was that you cannot embed anything into READ ONLY memory. Unless you're manufacturing your own Windows Mobile handset (and if you were, I doubt you'd be asking the question to begin with), it's not going to happen.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. ROM stands for **Read only memory**. Quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read-only_memory),

"Data stored in ROM cannot be modified, or can be modified only slowly or with difficulty, so it is mainly used to distribute firmware (software that is very closely tied to specific hardware, and unlikely to need frequent updates)."